# Github.app: can't connect to remote repository (not on github.com)

Tags: macos, git, ssh, github

I'm trying to host a git repository on my own webspace.

The repository has been set up via terminal+ssh and there were no problems, also I made a local clone of the repository with no problems.

Now I'm trying to use the github app to sync/push to the external repository which is causing big problems. The github app keeps prompting for the ssh password (I think its the ssh password - the box only says 'Password:'), even if I enter the correct one.

The url to the external repository seems to be correct, what have I done wrong (git beginner Oo)

Comment: I believe that github.app works only with github hosted repos

Comment: i dont think so - in the settings tab there is a input for "Primary remote repository" and the github.app pages says, it´s designd for github but should work fine with other servers

Comment: The GitHub.app works fine with remote repos not hosted on GitHub. Most likely, the app is trying to use your GitHub ssh key instead of the ssh key your remote repo is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found my error:

To sync your external non-github repository with your local one, your external repository mustn´t have the branch activated you want to sync.

i switched the external repository to an dummy-branch and then syncing works without problems...